# My app doesn't work after deployed on github pages(create-react-app)

Tags: reactjs, github, redux, react-router

I have tried to deploy my app throw Github Pages, It was built using create-react-app, material-ui, redux, redux-saga.
I believe it might have something to do with routes

though when I tried to publish it to get reviews, I got those errors:

```
Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'interest-cohort'.
react-dom.production.min.js:216 TypeError: Cannot read property 'row' of undefined
    at user-posts.page.js:46
    at oa (react-dom.production.min.js:157)
    at Hu (react-dom.production.min.js:267)
    at jl (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at El (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at Sl (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at vl (react-dom.production.min.js:243)
    at fl (react-dom.production.min.js:237)
    at Xl (react-dom.production.min.js:285)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:289
uu @ react-dom.production.min.js:216
n.callback @ react-dom.production.min.js:216
di @ react-dom.production.min.js:131
hu @ react-dom.production.min.js:220
Ml @ react-dom.production.min.js:259
t.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:18
$o @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
Pl @ react-dom.production.min.js:252
vl @ react-dom.production.min.js:243
fl @ react-dom.production.min.js:237
Xl @ react-dom.production.min.js:285
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:289
gl @ react-dom.production.min.js:244
rs @ react-dom.production.min.js:289
t.render @ react-dom.production.min.js:296
154 @ index.js:12
a @ (index):1
t @ (index):1
r @ (index):1
(anonymous) @ main.4bfcaa8c.chunk.js:1
react-dom.production.min.js:260 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'row' of undefined
    at user-posts.page.js:46
    at oa (react-dom.production.min.js:157)
    at Hu (react-dom.production.min.js:267)
    at jl (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at El (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at Sl (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at vl (react-dom.production.min.js:243)
    at fl (react-dom.production.min.js:237)
    at Xl (react-dom.production.min.js:285)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:289
```

and here is my Package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "re-deploy-task",
  "homepage": "https://kyrolosmagdy.github.io/task",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.0"
  }
}
```

Things I have tried:
1- create a new repo and pushes to it, try to rebuild it into there, it didn't work also.
2- create a new create-react-app, push it to github, redeploy, it works but not with that code.

please if anyone has any idea on how to solve it, don't hesitate to contact me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks good mate but try running

1. npm run build
2. npm run deploy

or just

1. npm run deploy

Comment: Could you please add more details regarding the app you're deploying? 
tech stack you're using, deployment script, etc.